# Scaling models for 3D print

Tags: 3d

So I need to print out [this](https://www.myminifactory.com/object/engine-1406) model, however with default sizes, one of the pieces is too large for my printer (M3D). I will need to scale it down.. the question is, do I need to scale the rest of the individual objects (pieces) in the same proportions, so I will be able to assemble all the parts afterwards ? This might be a bit of a stupid question, but I don't have any experience with 3D printing yet.. thank you.

Comment: (A belated) Welcome to Computer Graphics SE! I'm afraid questions about 3D printing are not on topic here, as this site is about computer graphics programming and research. Unfortunately, I can't think of any better Stack Exchange to redirect you to either. There *is* [a proposal for a 3D Printing SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82438/3d-printing-and-rapid-prototyping) in the commitment phase though, so you might want to keep an eye on that.

Answer (score 1):

Just like for any reduction or drawing, if you scale one part and not the other, their relative proportion is changed, so yes, aesthetic, matching, functionality are affected: scale everything in the same proportion. Nothing specific to 3D printing here.